# Force open internal links in HTTPS

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, https

I have a website that calls scripts and CSS internally:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick.css">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/imageLoader-global.js"></script>
<script src="js/slick.js"></script>
<script src="js/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/animation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/vivus.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/slick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The website opens in HTTPS but when I open the site and inspect the HTML, these internal links are opening in HTTP which is causing MIXED CONTENT and rendering a bad looking page.

How can I force all these links to open in HTTPS?

This is currently my HTACCESS file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

The website opens in HTTPS but the resources above are loading in HTTP.

Comment: You might be able to configure your server to redirect these resources to HTTPS when possible. (I believe there is a header your server might be able to send.)

Comment: Do a find of HTTP in the source code of your page, and check the media view in the browser. relative links are not the culprit of mixed content warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule after `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```